# OSGI : maven wrapped bundle throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException if it tries to access another wrapped bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse

As below dependencies are not OSGI-ready I wrapped them as follows :

```
  <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.maps/google-maps-services/0.9.2</bundle>
  <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.13.1</bundle>
```

Seems like my first bundle can't access second bundle, although I included it in my imports as follows:

```
<Import-Package>okhttp3,*</import-Package>
```

I am getting :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Authenticator
    at com.google.maps.GeoApiContext$Builder.<init>(GeoApiContext.java:318)
    at com.elavon.nabsd.creditsafe.beans.GooglePlacesAPIContext.<clinit>(GooglePlacesAPIContext.java:11)
    at com.elavon.nabsd.creditsafe.beans.AddressParser.getAddress(AddressParser.java:35)
    at com.elavon.nabsd.creditsafe.beans.AddressParser.dummyResponse(AddressParser.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.Authenticator not found by wrap_mvn_com.google.maps_google-maps-services_0.9.2 [1180]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

---

Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1552097042208
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Built-By: c041356
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/address-parser-blueprint.xml
Bundle-Description: XXX
Bundle-DocURL: XXX
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: XXX
Bundle-SymbolicName: address-parser
Bundle-Vendor: XXX
Bundle-Version: 1.0.24
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
DynamicImport-Package: *
Export-package: com.squareup.okhttp3,okhttp3
Import-Package: okhttp3,com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation,com.google.maps
 ,com.google.maps.errors,com.google.maps.model,org.apache.camel.componen
 t.jasypt,org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config,org.osgi.service.blueprint;ve
 rsion="[1.0.0,2.0.0)",org.slf4j,org.apache.camel.component.http4,org.ap
 ache.camel.component.jackson,com.squareup.okhttp3
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

---

```
wrap_mvn_com.squareup.okhttp3_okhttp_3.13.1 (1202)
--------------------------------------------------
Originally-Created-By = Apache Maven 3.6.0
Created-By = 1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation)
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Bnd-LastModified = 1552095323499
Generated-By-Ops4j-Pax-From = wrap:mvn:com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.13.1
Build-Jdk = 1.8.0_162
Built-By = jwilson
Automatic-Module-Name = okhttp3
Tool = Bnd-2.3.0.201405100607

Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
Bundle-SymbolicName = wrap_mvn_com.squareup.okhttp3_okhttp_3.13.1
Bundle-Version = 0
Bundle-Name = wrap_mvn_com.squareup.okhttp3_okhttp_3.13.1

Require-Capability =
        osgi.ee;filter:=(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))

Export-Package =
        okhttp3;uses:="javax.annotation,javax.net,javax.net.ssl,okio",
        okhttp3.internal;uses:="javax.annotation,javax.net.ssl,okhttp3,okhttp3.internal.cache,okhttp3.internal.connection,okhttp3.internal.http,okhttp3.internal.http2,okio",
        okhttp3.internal.annotations;uses:="javax.annotation,javax.annotation.meta",
        okhttp3.internal.cache;uses:="javax.annotation,okhttp3,okhttp3.internal.io,okio",
        okhttp3.internal.cache2,
        okhttp3.internal.connection;uses:="javax.annotation,javax.net.ssl,okhttp3,okhttp3.internal.http,okhttp3.internal.http2,okhttp3.internal.ws",
        okhttp3.internal.duplex,
        okhttp3.internal.http;uses:="javax.annotation,okhttp3,okhttp3.internal.connection,okio",
        okhttp3.internal.http1;uses:="okhttp3,okhttp3.internal.connection,okhttp3.internal.http,okio",
        okhttp3.internal.http2;uses:="okhttp3,okhttp3.internal.connection,okhttp3.internal.http,okio",
        okhttp3.internal.io;uses:=okio,
        okhttp3.internal.platform;uses:="javax.annotation,javax.net.ssl,okhttp3,okhttp3.internal.tls",
        okhttp3.internal.proxy,
        okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix,
        okhttp3.internal.tls;uses:=javax.net.ssl,
        okhttp3.internal.ws;uses:="javax.annotation,okhttp3,okio"
Import-Package =
        android.os;resolution:=optional,
        android.util;resolution:=optional,
        javax.annotation;resolution:=optional,
        javax.annotation.meta;resolution:=optional,
        javax.net;resolution:=optional,
        javax.net.ssl;resolution:=optional,
        javax.security.auth.x500;resolution:=optional,
        okio;resolution:=optional,
```

---

```
wrap_mvn_com.google.maps_google-maps-services_0.9.2 (1180)
----------------------------------------------------------
Created-By = 1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation)
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Bnd-LastModified = 1552091296783
Generated-By-Ops4j-Pax-From = wrap:mvn:com.google.maps/google-maps-services/0.9.2
Tool = Bnd-2.3.0.201405100607

Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
Bundle-SymbolicName = wrap_mvn_com.google.maps_google-maps-services_0.9.2
Bundle-Version = 0
Bundle-Name = wrap_mvn_com.google.maps_google-maps-services_0.9.2

Require-Capability =
        osgi.ee;filter:=(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))

Export-Package =
        com.google.maps;uses:="com.google.gson,com.google.maps.errors,com.google.maps.internal,com.google.maps.model,okhttp3",
        com.google.maps.errors,
        com.google.maps.internal;uses:="com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch,com.google.gson,com.google.gson.stream,com.google.maps,com.google.maps.errors,com.google.maps.model,okhttp3",
        com.google.maps.internal.ratelimiter,
        com.google.maps.model;uses:=com.google.maps.internal
Import-Package =
        com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch;resolution:=optional,
        com.google.gson;resolution:=optional,
        com.google.gson.stream;resolution:=optional,
        javax.crypto;resolution:=optional,
        javax.crypto.spec;resolution:=optional,
        okhttp3;resolution:=optional,
        okio;resolution:=optional,
        org.slf4j;resolution:=optional
```

Comment: Please post the Mainfest's from both wrapped bundles. Otherwise, it is just guessing and won't help you with diagnosing similar issues in the future.

Comment: @Ancoron Added manifest (some proprietary details removed). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, although the Imports are in place, the culprit may be with Bundle resolution order. If the issue gets solved by refreshing the "google-maps" Bundle, the it would be the "optional" import that makes the Bundle resolve before the Bundle "okhttp3".

Comment: Thank you, issue is almost resolved. After refreshing `google-maps` no more `ClassNotFoundException`. I changed the `start-level` on respective bundles to preserve order, but I still have to refresh `google-maps` manually after install. How can I get consistent behavior? I am using `maven-bundle-plugin` Please put your comment as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: @Ancoron I have one more question - `google-maps` already contains `okhttp3` as a transitive dependency. I added `okhttp3` only for troubleshooting purposes. Should not `google-maps` bundle resolve contained transitive dependencies?  I tried to add `<EmbedTransitive>`, but it did not help.

Comment: No, the `jar` file does not _contain_ the okhttp3 jar nor its classes so you have to add it separately.

Comment: @Ancoron Is there any way to implicitly pull all transitive dependencies of particular maven artifact? And another question - in case of transitive dependency - do I have to explicitly exclude transitive dependency to avoid conflict?

Comment: TL;DR: No and no. The wrapping processor ([bnd](https://bnd.bndtools.org/)) does not look into transitive dependencies and takes Maven dependency information (if available inside the jar: `META-INF/maven/...`) only as hinting for generating versions. As it doesn't care about transitive dependencies, there is also no need to "exclude" them. By default, the wrapping just generates the additional OSGi headers required in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and just copies the original `jar` contents as-is. To do that, `bnd` basically just inspects the `.class` files, not any Maven poms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapped bundles get the automatically discovered package dependencies as "optional", because there is no way to tell reliably whether some specific package will actually be required or not when using specific functionality provided by the bundle.

Hence, the existence of other bundles and their exported packages at the bundle resolving time determine, which packages are actually visible to the created class-loader of the resolved wrapped bundle.

In your case, the packages exported by bundle "okhttp3" where not available at the time the resolver searched for available package to import when resolving bundle "google-maps".

This in turn means that you need to make sure that either:

1. the bundle "okhttp3" is visible to the resolver at the time of resolving bundle "google-maps"
2. make sure that the required package imports are not "optional"

While the first option may seem easier, the second one is more reliable and flexible.

The [`wrap:` protocol](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/paxurl/pages/3833898/Wrap+Protocol) supports overwriting generated OSGi headers so that you can specify details to your needs. In our case, it would be:

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:com.google.maps/google-maps-services/0.9.2$overwrite=merge&amp;Import-Package=okhttp3,okio,*;resolution:=optional</bundle>
```

*(untested and only based on docs, though)*

**Notice**

Before using the `wrap` protocol, please have a look whether the desired library has already been OSGi-fied by some other project. One very good start is to have a look at the Bundles made available by the Apache ServiceMix project (which provides a `okhttp3` Bundle):

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/

Comment: Thank you, I will try. And I think `&` should be escaped in XML?

Comment: This is what I am getting now: 
`Unable to resolve 1294.0: missing requirement [1294.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch)`

Comment: Ah OK, then add `;resolution:=optional` after the `*`, that should tell it to still use optional for the other packages.

Comment: And now getting `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class okhttp3.OkHttpClient`, altought it is in `okhttp3` package. 
Unfortunatelt `ServiceMix` does not provide`okhttp3/3.13.1`

Comment: OK, if version 3.12.1_1 is not enough, then we are at the next level, at least. Do you have `okio` available?

Comment: OK, then I think you need to see which of the imports are not wired and try to make them available.

Comment: Ugh :) I think I am not following what is happening. `OkHttpClient` is in imported `okhttp3` package, but it is not resolved. Why is that?

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with class static members (inner static class)

Comment: OK, then the static initialization did result into some issue, most likely another class not found. Looking into the ServiceMix bundle, the following packages seem to be mandatory: `javax.annotation`, `javax.annotation.meta`, `javax.net`, `javax.net.ssl`, `javax.security.auth.x500`. If they are all wired, then it is most likely some missing dependency from `okio` bundle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189764/discussion-between-fg78nc-and-ancoron).

Comment: Could you please answer - If another class is not found why I am not getting exact stack trace, instead being pointed to okhttp3.OkHttpClient?

Comment: I think you should start a new question with the full stack trace and output of `la -s -t30` from Karaf shell as well as `bundle:headers` for the `okhttp3` and `okio` wrapped bundles and note which imports are not satisfied (usually shown red in the console).